# Is it possible to exchange data between X11 applications and RCP via DND?

Tags: gtk, swt, x11

XDND protocol is used for dnd support in X11 applications. 
http://www.newplanetsoftware.com/xdnd/

Gtk is based on X11 but gtk supports not only XDND protocal:

```
typedef enum
{
  GDK_DRAG_PROTO_MOTIF,
  GDK_DRAG_PROTO_XDND,
  GDK_DRAG_PROTO_ROOTWIN,     /* A root window with nobody claiming
               * drags */
  GDK_DRAG_PROTO_NONE,        /* Not a valid drag window */
  GDK_DRAG_PROTO_WIN32_DROPFILES, /* The simple WM_DROPFILES dnd */
  GDK_DRAG_PROTO_OLE2,        /* The complex OLE2 dnd (not implemented) */
  GDK_DRAG_PROTO_LOCAL            /* Intra-app */
} GdkDragProtocol;
```

And I inspected the value in SWT

```
public class GdkDragContext {     
    /** @field cast=(GdkDragProtocol) */
   public int protocol;
    /** @field cast=(gboolean) */
   public boolean is_source;
    /** @field cast=(GdkWindow *) */
   public long /*int*/ source_window;
    /** @field cast=(GdkWindow *) */
   public long /*int*/ dest_window;
    /** @field cast=(GList *) */
   public long /*int*/ targets;
    /** @field cast=(GdkDragAction) */
   public int actions;
    /** @field cast=(GdkDragAction) */
   public int suggested_action;
    /** @field cast=(GdkDragAction) */
   public int action; 
    /** @field cast=(guint32) */
   public int start_time;
   public static final int sizeof = OS.GdkDragContext_sizeof();
}
```

The value of protocol is 1 so it also used XDND protocol.
So is it possible to exchange data between X11 and SWT applications, i.e. drag from x11 to SWT or reverse?